# Apache-Pulsar cluster setup (multi broker) in local machine

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, apache-pulsar

I am able to run apache-pulsar standalone in local machine as docker container.

docker-compose.yml

> ```
> pulsar-standalone:
>     image: apachepulsar/pulsar
>     ports:
>       - "8080:8080"
>       - "6650:6650"
>     expose:
>       - 8080
>       - 6650
>     environment:
>       - PULSAR_MEM=" -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g"
>     command: >
>       /bin/bash -c
>       "bin/apply-config-from-env.py conf/standalone.conf
>       && bin/pulsar standalone"
> ```

Can anyone let me know how I can run **multi broker** setup for the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Sergii's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445283/9538447), I created a docker-compose file above in a manner similar to the [kafka stack depoyment](https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-stack-docker-compose).

The necessary configuration and yaml can be found in this [repo](https://github.com/rudh24/pulsar-stack-docker-compose)

This is a single pulsar cluster setup containing:

1. 3 node ZooKeeper cluster
2. 3 node BookKeeper cluster
3. 2 Pulsar broker nodes
4. 1 Pulsar proxy to allow access to pulsar from outside the docker-compose setup.

The setup uses [apachepulsar/pulsar:2.4.1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apachepulsar/pulsar/2.4.1/images/sha256-d7e2d4b0fe795a091669fb1309585f65c3ce7d666110029023d8f01fde3922e3?context=explore) docker image.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that by "multi-broker setup" you mean [Pulsar cluster](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-architecture-overview/). It is needed a bit more than a couple of brokers to achieve this goal. To create a Pulsar cluster the following tasks should be completed:

- Deploy ZooKeeper cluster
- Initialize Cluster metadata
- Deploy BookKeeper cluster
- (Finally) Deploy one or more Pulsar brokers

I am not aware of any existing docker-compose configurations to deploy a Pulsar cluster, but there a plenty of options to [deploy in Kubernetes](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/deploy-kubernetes/). For testing on a local machine, it is possible to start a Pulsar cluster in [minikube](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/deploy-kubernetes/#minikube) using [helm](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/deploy-kubernetes/#deploying-pulsar-components-helm).